# Monitoring cluster of micro services (web,queue,db,ha proxy)

Tags: nginx, architecture, health-monitoring, microservices

I am designing an architecture where all micro services are clustered.
For instance: 5 web server, 1 clustered db, 1 clustered queue system, 8 clustered workers (like send email,send sms,...) that consume from the queue (tasks are pushed by the web server)

I am wondering about the best practice in order to detect that each 'cluster of micro service' is healthy, and how to 'fail fast' the whole service in such case one of the micro service is unavailable.

All the service is sitting behind an nginx for ha proxy - should it be nginx that monitors everything and fails? How can I check the health of all the micro services?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an external monitoring service like [Pingometer](http://pingometer.com).

This lets you setup simple health checks (HTTP, HTTPS, Ping, etc.) at regular intervals and receive alerts if a node fails, is unavailable, or not responding with the correct content.

In your contact, you can setup a webhook which is fired when a service goes down. You can use the webhook to trigger a failover, change DNS records, etc.

We setup something similar and it's working quite well.

You can also use something internally to monitor nGinX itself (e.g. cheaping workers + respawning them), but this doesn't let you know that a service is functioning externally (like a monitoring service would).